# Quicksight datepicker for month only

Tags: datepicker, report, amazon-quicksight

I'm searching for a way to have month selection and that will serve as startdate and enddate for the date filtering.

I'm building a monthly report on quicksight, I try to use the last 31 days but that give information of multiple months

I already create date picker for those parameters but didn't find any way to limit the value to be the complete month only.

**Example** : if select the 12 september I desire to get the September values only (from the 1er to the 31th)

Any advice is welcome 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a new date filter (if you want, e.g., today to be the default you'll need to add a dynamic default against a data set that returns today)
[image]

Add a new control (I found naming this to be difficult, perhaps you're better at picking names than I am)
[image]

Add a new calculated field that returns `1` if the `truncDate` of your date field and the `truncDate` of your parameter are equal, otherwise return `0`

```
ifelse(
  truncDate("MM", {date}) = truncDate("MM", ${InMonth}),
  1,
  0
)
```

[image]

Finally, add a filter that checks where your calculated field is `1` and apply it to all visuals
[image]

Comment: interesting but doesn't give a dynamic month dropdown based on the data ?